# Full term path as product url

Tags: ubercart, path-aliases

Im using D7 and UC3. A product is multiple levels down:.

product list = cat1/sub2/sub-sub1/

Now using pathauto i'm trying to make the path of the product cat1/sub2/sub-sub1/product1 however i cant find the right tokens to do this. Best is can get is sub-sub1/product1 loosing the first two steps. In the breadcrum i do see the other levels, so the product knows its nested like that.But i cant seem to get the url to correspond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taxonomy reference of the content type must be set to 1. New tokens will become availible and differect ways to create a url like the above become possible

Answer (score 0):

This is not something given out-of-the-box, unfortunately. Been through this.
I have never used Ubercart, just Commerce, but I assume in both cases we have some kind of product entity and content type for displaying the product.

For the correct path and Pathauto, you'd have to use a pattern like this:

```
products/[product-category-field:parents:join:/]/[product:name]
```

However you might need to install Entity API and enable its submodule called Entity Tokens.

For the breadcrumb paths, I would suggest that you try out Path Breadcrumbs. Even though it requires some setup work for all the context, I found it more reliable than Context or other Taxonomy Breadcrumbs or Menu Breadcrumbs modules out there.